# Disable HTTP referrer in tor-browser caused risk?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

In the URL bar of tor-browser, go to about:config.

In the page of about:config, find `Network.http.sendRefererHeader` then change the value to 1.

Any risk?

Answer (score 0):

This image shows what `Network.http.sendRefererHeader` does:

[image]

The Tor browser has set `Network.http.sendRefererHeader` to 2 by default so it is allowing all requests. So by changing it, you will obviously have a different browser fingerprint and you can easily be identified (you would be the only Tor browser user who is blocking requests). The Tor Browser's settings are already the best they can be so I wouldn't recommend changing this.

Also, the Tor browser makes `Network.http.sendRefererHeader` to 2 by default because there really is no need to block requests as seen here:

> When leaving a .onion domain we set the Referer header to an empty string by providing a preference, network.http.referer.hideOnionSource, and setting it to true. That avoids leaking information which might be especially problematic in the case of transitioning from a .onion domain to one reached over clearnet.

> Apart from that **we haven't disabled or restricted the Referer
> ourselves because of the non-trivial number of sites that rely on the
> Referer header to "authenticate" image requests and deep-link
> navigation on their sites. Furthermore, there seems to be no real
> privacy benefit to taking this action by itself in a vacuum, because
> many sites have begun encoding Referer URL information into GET
> parameters when they need it to cross HTTP to HTTPS scheme
> transitions.** Google's +1 buttons are the best example of this
> activity.

Quote source: https://2019.www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/

Image source: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Referrer

Comment: Tor developers must have a bigger reason to design tor-browser to  send HTTP Referer by default, because setting the default value to 1 for all looks easy for the Tor developers.

Comment: @torbnxx yes, there is another reason I just added which I forgot to mention.

Comment: @torbnnxx, please the read the quote I added. Blocking the HTTP referer requests are pointless because sites can just encode the Referer URL information into GET parameters when they need it to cross HTTP to HTTPS scheme transitions. So there really should be no reason to block these requests and I hope you understand why now.

Comment: Thank you, you should be voted up.